# Ionic make a pdf report in Arabic language

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, pdfmake

When I develop an ionic app i tried to make a pdf report  in Arabic language using pdfmake library i found language not correct just found unfamiliar characters can help me

Answer (score 0):

Currently, PDFMake doesn't support any RTL language (Arabic, Hebrew..etc). you can check out the following [issue](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/315) for updates, but it seems that it's not going to be implmented any time soon.

You can try another library that supports arabic characters like [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF).

Comment: you need to change the font used

Comment: what font must be use?